# SEO punishment?

Tags: seo

My current website URLs have the following format:

```
http://website.com/car-report/ferrari-car-report
http://website.com/car-report/audi-car-report
http://website.com/car-report/bmw-car-report
```

Does this have negative SEO impact (especially from Google's side)? Or is it OK to "repeat" the `"car-report"` category in the URL? Does it need to be as follows?

```
http://website.com/car-report/ferrari
http://website.com/car-report/audi
http://website.com/car-report/bmw
```

Comment: Sorry but there is already a vast amount of questions and answers on Pro Webmasters regarding the usage of keywords in URL structure. To save your time and further disappointment please ensure you visit our help centre.

Comment: No need to apologize. Thank you for the link above (marked as duplicate). I wouldn't find it myself so I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is the shorter/cleaner URL's, the better.

Repeating 'car-report' is just unnecessary and there is little point implementing anything on a website which will have no benefit to the end user or a search engine.

That being said, it is unlikely going to cause a negative impact unless it was excessive/spammy (not so in your provided example).